# Gerar sequence para campo

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

É possivel eu criar um *sequence* sem mudar o campo para id?

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
Map(x => x.DocumentoNumero);
```

Usando este exemplo, gostaria de manter um *sequence* para `DocumentoNumero`, mas ao mesmo tempo tenho id que já esta fazendo isto e preciso mantê-lo desta forma.

Comment: qual o objectivo do documentoNumero? é ser igual ao id?

Comment: Não, o id segue gerando em sequencia para cada documento..
O DocumentoNumero não será unico, apenas deve gerar uma sequencia quando solicitado ou caso ele seja gravado como null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990319/have-a-custom-setter-on-property-for-ef-code-first-model-entity

nao percebi bem, queres ter controlo sobre o "set" dessa propriedade. da uma olhada neste link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz tempo já, mas vou deixar aqui como resolvi para minha atender à necessidade:

```
    protected void SetSequence(string sequenceName, int value)
    {
        string sqlQuery = string.Empty;

        if (value == 0)
            sqlQuery = $"SELECT setval('{sequenceName}', 1, false);"; // o próximo nextval() retornara {value} (1)
        else
            sqlQuery = $"SELECT setval('{sequenceName}', {value}, true);"; // o próximo nextval() retornara {value}+1

        Session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlQuery).ExecuteUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990319/have-a-custom-setter-on-property-for-ef-code-first-model-entity

codigo tirado desse link.

```
private string documentoNumero;
     public string DocumentoNumero
     {
          get { return documentoNumero; }
          set
          {
               // aqui podes por a logica do campo jobTitle = value
          }
     }
```

Comment: quase isso, na verdade se tivesse alguma forma de criar um sequence (via nhibernate) sem vincular ao campo, para ser chamado pela aplicação apenas quando necessário já seria suficiente. A idéia seria manter a integridade dessa informação, no caso de varios usuarios acessarem ao mesmo tempo

Comment: http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/creating-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate.html